# discord.js Editting Slash Command Interaction Messages

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I'm using discord.js with this code here:

```javascript
client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({
  data: {
    type: 4,
    data: {
      content: "Getting Data..."
    }
  }
})
```

I would like to be able to edit this message afterwards, but everything I have seen requireds a message id, and I seem to be unable to get the message id off of this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit an interaction response with this patch request (See: [Followup Messages](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands#followup-messages)):

```
PATCH /webhooks/<application_id>/<interaction_token>/messages/@original
```

Basic example using the [axios library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios):

```js
axios.patch(`https://discord.com/api/v8/webhooks/${appId}/${interaction.token}/messages/@original`, { content: 'New content' });
```

The answer to this request will also contain the message-id.

Here is an example function that will edit the original message either as plain text or an embed object and returns the discord message object for further usage (e.g. add reply emojis etc.):

```js
const editInteraction = async (client, interaction, response) => {
    // Set the data as embed if reponse is an embed object else as content
    const data = typeof response === 'object' ? { embeds: [ response ] } : { content: response };
    // Get the channel object by channel id:
    const channel = await client.channels.resolve(interaction.channel_id);
    // Edit the original interaction response:
    return axios
        .patch(`https://discord.com/api/v8/webhooks/${appId}/${interaction.token}/messages/@original`, data)
        .then((answer) => {
            // Return the message object:
            return channel.messages.fetch(answer.data.id)
        })
};
```

Also instead of sending an initial message like "getting data..." you also can send an empty response of type 5. This is the build-in method and displays a little loading animation too :) [See here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands#interaction-response) (One advantage is that this way no "edited" appears.)

```js
client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({
    data: {
        type: 5,
    },
})
```