# Editing original interaction response discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

With interactions in the new Discord.js update, I want to be able to edit the original response that I send. I want to be able to send a message something like "grabbing data...", and then edit that. In the API documentation, it says this:

```
Edit Original Interaction Response

PATCH/webhooks/{application.id}/{interaction.token}/messages/@original // this being the method to edit it.

Edits the initial Interaction response. Functions the same as Edit Webhook Message.
```

I don't really get this though, because I don't know what @original means in terms of code. the rest of it works, I just cant figure out how to put @original in there. i would assume it is the message id of the original response, but that returns "unknown message"

Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: Hi, I posted an example to a similar question, maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67247833/11249441